# How do earthquakes of different strengths affect buildings of different heights?

Tags: classical-mechanics, material-science, frequency, resonance, earthquake

Why is it that short buildings respond more to high frequency oscillations while tall buildings respond more to low frequency oscillations?

I would assume that how they react is related to the natural frequency of the buildings so

$$f=\frac{1}{2\pi}\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$$

To decrease natural frequency, one can add mass ($\sim$ tall buildings) thus it makes sense to state that tall buildings respond more to low frequency oscillations and vice versa. Is this the true reason behind this phenomenon?

Comment: You seem to be modelling a building as a spring-mass system, with all the mass concentrated at one point. Perhaps it would make more sense to model it like a massive *string* instead of a spring, with one end fixed (and vibrating) and the other free? That way, there would be multiple natural resonance frequencies...

Comment: You are absolutely right, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: If this were true, making a short building with high density bricks would be dangerous. What do you think?